# How to make an object follow the camera?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I have a little scene in OpenGL, and I want to have a sword to the right and slightly forward, just like in minecraft for example, and it needs to move with my camera. I have absolutely no ideea how to do this. The only thing I know is that I have to change the model matrix for the sword when the camera moves. I have prepared in my camera class 3 functions, like this, for getting the camera position, target and up direction, but that's about all I could think of:

```
myCamera.getCameraPosition();
myCamera.getCameraTarget();
myCamera.getCameraUp();
```

Maybe some more info about the structure of my code will help. I have in the main loop a renderScene and processInput function. In processInput all i do is check if either WASD is pressed or if there is mouse movement, in order to move the camera. A keyboard press check looks like this:

```
if (pressedKeys[GLFW_KEY_W]) {
    myCamera.move(gps::MOVE_FORWARD, cameraSpeed);
    view = myCamera.getViewMatrix();

    myBasicShader.useShaderProgram();
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
}
```

And in renderScene I call other functions to render my objects, like renderSword, which looks like this:

```
void renderSword(gps::Shader shader) {
    shader.useShaderProgram();

    glUniformMatrix4fv(swordModelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(swordModel));

    sword.Draw(shader);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just draw the sword using its very own tranformation matrix that's managed independently from the rest of the world.